# Armory - Change Amounts Not Showing

Tags: armory

So I imported a watch-only copy of my wallet on the online version of Armory but my balance in the wallet is missing all the amounts I previously received as change. The transaction history clearly shows that a certain amount of BTC were sent back to the same wallet as change but the transaction is grayed out and the amount given as change is not part of my total balance. The change addresses are also not associated with the wallet.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you set up a watch only HD wallet? If you are only watching a single address (and not all change addresses from an HD wallet) your problem makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You may just need to wait for the transactions to confirm. Be sure that your bitcoind is caught up.